# How can I use javascript to load a new page when a key is pressed down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, window.location

I have:

```
<a id="nextPage" href="somepage.php?name=foo">Next Page</a>
```

When someone presses an arrow button on the keyboard, I want to redirect the user to the href contained in the anchor tag. How can I do this with javascript/jquery?

I was thinking something like this:

```
window.location = $('#nextPage').attr('href');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: When I press an arrow key I expect my browser to scroll the page within the browser window.

Comment: @Yaypaul - he's asking about key presses, not mouse clicks.

Comment: if it's logically the next page, you should give the anchor a [`rel` value of `next`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-next) (`<a rel="next" ...>`), which would allow you to get the next location with `$('[rel="next"]').attr('href');`

Comment: Ok then, read http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: Or of course you can just wait for someone to add a complete free example and learn nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {alert(event.type);
    if (event.which == 37) {
        $('#prevPage').trigger('click');
        //or
        window.location = $('#prevPage').attr('href');
    } else if (event.which == 39) {
        $('#nextPage').trigger('click');
        //or
        window.location = $('#nextPage').attr('href');
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/VprbW/2/

You can also access the `href` attribute of one of the links like this to perform faster:

```
window.location = document.getElementById('nextPage').href;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the onkeypress event.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml

Describes how to use this event and also gives a keycode generator for whatever button you need.